# Figaro - Rails Missing secret_key_base for development

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I've just switched to using the Figaro gem v1.0.0 with Rails 4.1.6.
Since deleting my secrets.yml file I now get the error:

Unexpected error while processing request: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'development' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`

Do i still need the secrets.yml file - isn't this the job of Figaro's application.yml file?

My application.yml file is like

```
development:
  secret_key_base: 56....
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looking into the Railties gem at https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/application.rb you can see the secrets method defined which includes a fallback for secret_key_base

```
 def secrets #:nodoc:
  @secrets ||= begin
    secrets = ActiveSupport::OrderedOptions.new
    yaml = config.paths["config/secrets"].first
    if File.exist?(yaml)
      require "erb"
      all_secrets = YAML.load(ERB.new(IO.read(yaml)).result) || {}
      env_secrets = all_secrets[Rails.env]
      secrets.merge!(env_secrets.symbolize_keys) if env_secrets
    end

    # Fallback to config.secret_key_base if secrets.secret_key_base isn't set
    secrets.secret_key_base ||= config.secret_key_base

    secrets
  end
end
```

In config/application.rb adding the following resolves the issue

```
config.secret_key_base = Figaro.env.secret_key_base
```

Comment: Kudos on theoretical explanation of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Figaro gem but try these, create the config/secret.yml file and inside write:

```
development:
  secret_key_base: <%= ENV['secret_key_base'] %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was just informed that as of Rails 4.1.x, `config/secrets.yml` **does** need to be uploaded to heroku. Rails will no longer look directly at its ENV in order to find its `secret_key_base`.

So `secrets.yml` needs to come off of the `.gitignore` file, and your project would need to be recommited and re-pushed to heroku.

(`secrets.yml` would still get its values from heroku's ENV, which would still be loaded up via Figaro the same way as before - `figaro heroku:set -e production`. Use `heroku config` to get a nice quick look at your ENV variables to confirm they are there)